# How to replace values in a column randomly using values from a list on Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, random, replace

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'Names':['Antonio','Bianca','Chad','Damien','Edward','Frances','George'],'Sport':['Basketball','Placeholder','Football','Placeholder','Tennis','Placeholder','Placeholder']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Names','Sport'])
```

I want to replace the value 'Placeholder' randomly with any value from the following list:

```
extra_sports = ['Football','Basketball','Tennis','Rowing']
```

The final outcome should look something like this whereby the value 'Placeholder' is now gone and replaced randomly with values from the list:

```
data = {'Names':['Antonio','Bianca','Chad','Damien','Edward','Frances','George'],'Sport':['Basketball','Tennis','Football','Rowing','Tennis','Football','Tennis']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Names','Sport'])
```

And if possible how would I implement random.seed so that I can reproduce the results.

Comment: I think both DataFrames are same in question.

Comment: Amended it my apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need replace only values `Placeholder` with list, for length of list use `sum` of boolean `True`s for correct length of benerated array:

```
extra_sports = ['Football','Basketball','Tennis','Rowing']
   
np.random.seed(1) 
m = df['Sport'].eq('Placeholder')
df.loc[m, 'Sport'] = np.random.choice(extra_sports, size=m.sum())
print (df)
     Names       Sport
0  Antonio  Basketball
1   Bianca  Basketball
2     Chad    Football
3   Damien      Rowing
4   Edward      Tennis
5  Frances    Football
6   George    Football
```

Comment: Is there a seed element to this so that the final column can be replicated.

Comment: @Quincy I think you can add before solution `np.random.seed(1)`